# How to Improve FLVPlayback - Reduce Choppy Video

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, video

I have a 1920x1080 video playing inside a flash project with the same dimensions, using Firefox. The project is using CC2015, Latest Flash Player, Latest FF. I should note that this project is using **locally** stored videos.

I'm using AS3, `FLVPlayback` component, and the videos have been compressed (by production).

Heres the code that uses the playback component

```
function playVideoByString(source: String): void {
    hideTheButtons();
    attractTimer.stop();
    movie_container = new MovieClip();
    addChild(movie_container);
    movie_container.x = 0;
    movie_container.y = 0;

    launchVideo(movie_container, source);
}

function launchVideo(vBox, vFile): void {
    attractTimer.stop();
    flvPlayer = new FLVPlayback();
    flvPlayer.source = vFile;
    flvPlayer.skinAutoHide = true;
    flvPlayer.skinBackgroundColor = 0x000000;
    flvPlayer.width = 1920;
    flvPlayer.height = 1080;
    flvPlayer.autoRewind = false;
    cuePt.time = 0.9;
    cuePt.name = "ASpt1";
    cuePt.type = "actionscript";
    flvPlayer.addASCuePoint(cuePt);
    vBox.addChild(flvPlayer);
    // adding listeners in here
    flvPlayer.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, cp_listener);
    flvPlayer.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}
```

Playback is experiencing some degradation in the form of what looks like frames dropping, or "stutter." The animations look glass smooth when the MP4 is opened in Firefox and played back using FFs player. They also look fine when played in QuickTime (obviously). The video is 30FPS, as is the Flash Project, though from what I understand, FLVPlayback will use the videos encoded frame rate regardless of Flash's FPS.

Is there anything I can do to improve the video playback, and possibly smooth the videos out without loosing quality?

Comment: Did you try using [stageVideo](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=nqYkUqj1Osi20QXAhoHoDQ#q=as3+%22stageVideo%22)? It was specifically made to handle accelerated video via GPU (smoother playback of HD data)

Comment: I have not. In fact I didn't know there was an alternative. From the looks of it, it sounds like it would require adding a new function, one that checks the availability of Stage.stageVideo and if available, `launchStageVideo` function is called, and the video is played. Honestly, I'm not even sure how I would do all that. I'm still reading the API doc and it's starting to sound like I'll have to rewrite a bunch of code I'm not familiar with. Would I be able to repurpose any of my existing code above?